How can I install leaflet on npm properly
I am trying to install leaflet library on npm but for some reason it gives error. And I have reinstalled npm, cleared cache, removed node_modules and tried again but still didnt work.
nasersobhan@Nasers-MacBook-Pro Library % npm i leaflet
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/nasersobhan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/20/8f
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/leaflet: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/nasersobhan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/20/8f'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/nasersobhan/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/20/8f
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /Users/nasersobhan/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal

I wanted to install leaflet but got an error.

Try looking up some of the errors given to identify the cause - e.g. 'EEXIST' implies the error is because it already exists (so delete the old or overwrite it?); whilst 'EACCESS' implies that you don't have sufficient user privileges to write to the required directory, try to run with elevated privileges ('sudo' / 'Run as admin') or change owner to your user (e.g. 'chown ...')

Try to rerun the same command with higher rights.
On windows try to open an admin terminal and run your command
npm i leaflet

On linux run the command prefixed with sudo
sudo npm i leaflet

This method grants npm permissions to install packages ( bypass EACCES: permission denied ).
However, using sudo with npm commands is generally not recommended due to potential security risks.

Thank you sudo did the magic. Sometimes its simpler than you think. Thank you!!

@JamilRahmanMowahid - If this answer solved the problem please consider marking it as your solution and perhaps up-vote the answer :)
